# Spring 4 Optional<List<String>> @RequestParam

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-web

Using [java.util.Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) as a spring controller [request parameter](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/28/spring-framework-4-1-spring-mvc-improvements).

For simple values (int, String, etc) it works as expected but for a parameter which is of type `List<String>` or `String[]` and for which I pass multiple values:

```
    mockMvc.perform(get("/get").param("param", "value1", "value2"))
```

it always picks just one value of the passed ones.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object get(@RequestParam(name = "param") Optional<String[]> array) {
    // the array will have just 1 element : 'value1'
}
```

Comment: `@RequestParam(name = "param", required = false) String[] array` would work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this issue will be resolved in next spring web release 4.3 https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13418